# How to set Class<?> as property value in spring application context?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Is there a way to configure spring application context so it will initialize the setter with value of type Class?

I need to initialize that structure: `Map<Class<?>, Object>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="myBean">
  <!-- This will set a map onto the property classMap of myBean -->
  <property name="classMap">
    <map key-type="java.lang.Class">
      <entry key="java.lang.String" value="A String keyed by the class 'java.lang.String'" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: it appears that <entry key="java.lang.String" value-ref="blabla"/> is sufficient to have object of type Class<String> as a key