# Spring Beans - wiring class as key and value to map

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

How would one wire key/value pairs into a property like this ?

```
 private Map<Class<? extends ObjectOne>, Class<? extends ObjectTwo>> classes;
```

Both ObjectOne and ObjectTwo are abstract if that is of any help.

Comment: Perhaps use class names int the spring configuration and get the rela classes for them in the setter.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably define the bean in appcontext as

```
    <bean id="id" class = "pathtoyourclass">
    <property name="propname">
    <map>
    <entry key-ref="id of class extends objectone's bean" value-ref="id of class extends objecttwo's bean">
    </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095637/how-to-set-class-as-property-value-in-spring-application-context) has bit confused me it seems that there is nothing to it wiring map like I declared.

```
             <map>
                <entry key="org.sandbox.ObjectOneExt"
                       value="org.sandbox.ObjectTwoExt" />

                <!-- where ObjectOneExt and ObjectTwoExt are extended from ObjectOne and ObjectTwo respectively -->
            </map>
```

Spring (at least 3.1) handled this the way I wanted. So all that is required is to specify full class path to an object in key and value. The "key-type="java.lang.Class"" which is demonstrated in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095637/how-to-set-class-as-property-value-in-spring-application-context) somehow made spring confused but once removed worked like a charm.